# Angular dynamically change ng-repeat name

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have **ng-repeat** in my html. how I can add ng-repeat with dynamically changes name.

```
<div ng-repeat="category in categories"> //external repeat

<div ng-repeat="data in categoryData.{{categoryName here}}">
```

// want add instead *.{{categoryName here}}* defined (concrete) name from external loop.

In result I want have many places in html and different data for each place that will be places in **categoryData.NameOfCategory** .NameOfCategory will replaced to concrete name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
<div ng-repeat="category in categories"> 
<div ng-repeat="data in categoryData[category.name]">
```

Comment: this give SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Comment: you dont need the dot there

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="data in categoryData.['categoryName']">
```